# VSCode debugger failed when running ./scripts/code.sh

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When debugging VSCode source code, after run `yarn watch`.
The other terminal is running `./scripts/code.sh`.
But it failed.

```
dai:vscode/ (main) $ ./scripts/code.sh                                                                                                             [16:55:58]
yarn run v1.22.21
$ node build/lib/electron
✨  Done in 3.46s.
[16:56:26] Synchronizing built-in extensions...
[16:56:26] You can manage built-in extensions with the --builtin flag
[16:56:26] [github] ms-vscode.js-debug-companion@1.1.2 ✔︎
[16:56:26] Downloading extension from GH: ms-vscode.js-debug@1.84.0 ...
[16:56:26] [github] ms-vscode.vscode-js-profile-table@1.0.7 ✔︎
/Users/dai/workspace/icbc/vscode/build/lib/fetch.js:76
            throw new Error(`Request ${ansiColors.magenta(url)} failed with status code: ${response.status}`);
                  ^

Error: Request https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/releases/tags/v1.84.0 failed with status code: 403
    at fetchUrl (/Users/dai/workspace/icbc/vscode/build/lib/fetch.js:76:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Stream instance at:
    at Stream.onerror (node:internal/streams/legacy:62:12)
    at Stream.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Stream.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at next (/Users/dai/workspace/icbc/vscode/node_modules/map-stream/index.js:75:19)
    at /Users/dai/workspace/icbc/vscode/node_modules/map-stream/index.js:85:7
    at /Users/dai/workspace/icbc/vscode/build/lib/fetch.js:29:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.18.2
```

I have tried running `yarn cache clean` and `yarn` again. But it not worked.
In my browser, api 'https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/releases/tags/v1.84.0' is ok as below.

```
{
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/releases/126660072",
    "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/releases/126660072/assets",
    "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/releases/126660072/assets{?name,label}",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/releases/tag/v1.84.0",
    "id": 126660072,
    "author": {
        "login": "connor4312",
        "id": 2230985,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIyMzA5ODU=",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2230985?v=4",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/connor4312",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/orgs",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/repos",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": true
    },
    "node_id": "RE_kwDOC9rrrM4HjK3o",
    "tag_name": "v1.84.0",
    "target_commitish": "main",
    "name": "v1.84.0",
    "draft": false,
    "prerelease": false,
    "created_at": "2023-10-25T17:57:26Z",
    "published_at": "2023-10-25T18:41:44Z",
    "assets": [
        {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/releases/assets/132329796",
            "id": 132329796,
            "node_id": "RA_kwDOC9rrrM4H4zFE",
            "name": "js-debug-dap-v1.84.0.tar.gz",
            "label": null,
            "uploader": {
                "login": "connor4312",
                "id": 2230985,
                "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIyMzA5ODU=",
                "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2230985?v=4",
                "gravatar_id": "",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312",
                "html_url": "https://github.com/connor4312",
                "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/followers",
                "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/following{/other_user}",
                "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/gists{/gist_id}",
                "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
                "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/subscriptions",
                "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/orgs",
                "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/repos",
                "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/events{/privacy}",
                "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/received_events",
                "type": "User",
                "site_admin": true
            },
            "content_type": "application/x-gzip",
            "state": "uploaded",
            "size": 1437172,
            "download_count": 10118,
            "created_at": "2023-10-25T18:41:25Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-10-25T18:41:28Z",
            "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/releases/download/v1.84.0/js-debug-dap-v1.84.0.tar.gz"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/releases/assets/132329863",
            "id": 132329863,
            "node_id": "RA_kwDOC9rrrM4H4zGH",
            "name": "ms-vscode.js-debug.1.84.0.vsix",
            "label": null,
            "uploader": {
                "login": "connor4312",
                "id": 2230985,
                "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIyMzA5ODU=",
                "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2230985?v=4",
                "gravatar_id": "",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312",
                "html_url": "https://github.com/connor4312",
                "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/followers",
                "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/following{/other_user}",
                "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/gists{/gist_id}",
                "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
                "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/subscriptions",
                "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/orgs",
                "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/repos",
                "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/events{/privacy}",
                "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/connor4312/received_events",
                "type": "User",
                "site_admin": true
            },
            "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "state": "uploaded",
            "size": 1535744,
            "download_count": 7615,
            "created_at": "2023-10-25T18:41:28Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-10-25T18:41:31Z",
            "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/releases/download/v1.84.0/ms-vscode.js-debug.1.84.0.vsix"
        }
    ],
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/tarball/v1.84.0",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/zipball/v1.84.0",
    "body": "## What's Changed\r\n* fix: error when processing private properties with a map by @connor4312 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1825\r\n* chore: remove old codeql pipeline by @connor4312 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1826\r\n* fix: make sourcemap renames scope aware by @connor4312 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1827\r\n* fix: auto-attach/debug terminal not working in nightly by @connor4312 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1831\r\n* fix: envFiles variables appending rather than replacing in attach by @connor4312 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1832\r\n* fix: eval webpack config breakpoints not setting by @connor4312 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1833\r\n* fix: handle getPossibleBreakpoints response from hermes by @connor4312 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1841\r\n* Add suppression comments by @rzhao271 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1845\r\n* fix: also use script ID bps if there is a different embeddername by @connor4312 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1846\r\n* chore: fix codeql warnings by @connor4312 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1847\r\n* chore(deps-dev): bump @babel/traverse from 7.14.7 to 7.23.2 by @dependabot in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1849\r\n* fix: cache-bust sourcemaps if the underlying content changes by @connor4312 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1850\r\n* fix test flakes by @connor4312 in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1851\r\n* feat: Tidying Up of Instrumentation Breakpoints by @OnesAndZer0s in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1853\r\n\r\n## New Contributors\r\n* @rzhao271 made their first contribution in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1845\r\n* @OnesAndZer0s made their first contribution in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1853\r\n\r\n**Full Changelog**: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/compare/v1.83.0...v1.84.0",
    "mentions_count": 4
}
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Ok, I have replaced my image with code text.

Comment: help...........